# Short story about aliens who communicate by smell

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm looking for a satiric short story about first encounter. (I probably read it in the seventies, so it's not so new). A UFO comes to Earth, and a pool-like thing comes out with alien-like octopuses in it. The humans try to make contact in every way possible: speech, music and films, but in vain. In the end, the aliens depart and we read their report, written by smell, saying that humanity is not worth making contact because they produce only weak smell. Can anyone remember this?

Comment: I'm sure it's not the story you're looking for, but you may enjoy "The Curse Of Fatal Death". https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Do-wDPoC6GM

Comment: Also not what you're looking for, but this immediately reminded me of "The Scent of their Arrival" by Mercurio D. Rivera, which deals with smell-communicating aliens dealing with *incoming* first contact. It was published by Interzone in 2008, and is in his collection "Across the Event Horizon", if you're curious.

Comment: There were some captured aliens in a book called _The Jupiter Theft_ by Donald Moffit who communicated by smell (and used it as an offensive weapon), I enjoyed the book a lot.

Answer (score 3):

The story you are looking for in Russian is called "Contacts will not" ("Контактов не будет"). It was written by Russian writer Ilya Varshavskiy (Илья Варшавский). What this story can be called in English - I do not know.

Comment: Possibly this ("The Conflict") from ISFDB?  http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?53850

Comment: @ImaginaryEvents Not _The Conflict_. That is about a mother who is jealous of her robotic nanny.

Comment: I guess it would translate as "No further contact", but it may be the case that this story has never actually been translated into English